# VMware: How to Reset a Hung Guest

Tags: vmware-workstation

Say, something goes wrong with a guest. It hangs, or you lose power, basically it just is not working any longer. The workstation does not even allow you to start this guest any longer. How would one clear/reset/delete the current session, so one was left with just the state of the guest's harddrive?

VMware Workstation 12
Windows 7 64x Guest, Windows 10 64x Host

Comment: Have you tried to use [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DkuMg.png) options ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like There are no options. The workstation refuses to have anything to do with the guest any longer.